# An issue tracker with per-issue access control

Tags: webapp-rec

I am looking for an issue tracker/bug tracker where I can decide access control on a per-issue basis. Issue trackers I've seen (Trac, Redmine, JIRA) each do that on a level of project, so I'd have to make a project for every subset of people allowed to see given issue and this is prohibitive in my use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could could try out fogbugz http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/ however it isnt free but it is really good.

Persmissions info can be [found here](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBUGZ/docs/50/Articles/Permissions.html)

Guide on managing them - https://developers.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W119

Comment: I don't see this feature on the feature list. Is it really there?

Comment: @liori after rereading your question I dont fully get what your after however there a lot of plugins for fogbugz that may meet your requirements http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/plugins/

Comment: I have found none.

Comment: @liori could you give a more detailed explanation of what your after? As Im unsure as to your needs

Comment: Exactly what I wrote: I want to decide who can see and who can modify each ticket.

Comment: @Liori updated my anwser to show more about permissions within fogbugz

Answer (score 0):

Bugzilla allows the *bug submitter* to designate individual bugs as security bugs or otherwise confidential. In that case they will only be seen by a previously designated list of staff, and will not be public.

Comment: Is there only a single "security" group, or maybe I can create multiple such groups?